# Sum from $1$ to $(N-1)/2$

Tags: summation

On a piece of coursework I am working on, we are asked to perform some calculations involving the following:
[image]

As you can see, it is possible for $(N-1)/2$ to be fractional, e.g. in the case $N=4$. How exactly do I go about computing this sum, as I have never seen fractions being involved before.

Comment: If not explained differently, indices are positive integers, so in this case just $k=\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor$. Often there is the requirement added that $N$ is odd (two lines earlier). For formulas, please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: If $\theta_i$ does not depend on $N$, you can take $N=2m+1$.

Comment: Are you able to do this sum for $N$ odd(where the index $\frac{N-1}{2}$ is an integer)? If so, then the first comment tells you that the answer for $N=2m$ is the same as the answer to $2m-1$ for all $m \geq 2$.

Comment: If $N$ is required to be odd, then there's of course no problem. If $N$ can be even, the most natural interpretation would be that you only sum the $k$ that satisfy $k\le (N-1)/2$. However, it would be more proper for this to be explicitly specified with the floor function.